# Unity : why parameters not being passed from script A to script B?

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, parameters

so I have 2 scripts and I am setting some parameters that id like to be sent from one to the other, but I'm not sure its being called?

This script SaveDetails.cs

```
public class SaveDetails : MonoBehaviour
{
    //In inspector, drag in the GameObject that has this script attached to it
    public ViewDetails accessDetails = new ViewDetails();

    void SendDetails()
    { 
        //newFolder and NewTextfile are strings that are paths
        accessDetails.GetDetails(newFolder, NewTextfile);
    }
}
```

Send to this script ViewDetails.cs

```
public class ViewAlbum : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject EditAlbumCanvas, ViewAlbumCanvas;
    public Text DetailsName, DetailsDate, DetailsDesc;

    public void GetDetails(string DetailsPath, string TextFilePath)
    {
        //This happens
        EditCanvas.SetActive(false);
        ViewCanvas.SetActive(true);

        //This Text UI remains empty. Does that mean DetailsPath is empty?
        DetailsPath = AlbumName.text;
    }
}
```

Comment: a monobehavior should be instantiated together with the gameobject it belongs to, and then referenced in the original script, not created via a new constructor! Otherwise it will not be part of the scene and only exist in memory. also, since you called the new() constructor in savedetails, this means that the objects in ViewAlbum are all null (unless given a value elsewhere)

Comment: @LucasHarskamp I think it's juste a mistake in the comment it says: `//In inspector, drag in the GameObject that has this script attached to it` So the reference is not the object initialized by the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply inverted the two term:

```
DetailsPath = AlbumName.text;
```

What you should write is:

```
AlbumName.text = DetailsPath;
```

And why are you instantiating `accessDetails`? Just drag it in the editor as your comment says

```
//In inspector, drag in the GameObject that has this script attached to it
public ViewDetails accessDetails;
```

Comment: @user2395639 it happens :)

Answer (score 0):

In Unity, you can't really use Type variable = new()....

Monobehaviour are Unity component, they are created by Unity if they are in your scene (in the hierarchy).

Their is multiple way to achieve what you want to do :

- 1 : Use a public / serialized private field in SaveDetails and link it using the editor, this is done before runtime
- 2 : Find you object at runtime, and use it there
- 3 : Use the singleton pattern for things that you only need as a One-object only (like managers for audio, ui, or whatever) and use the Awake method to set your instance.

Comment: I think it's juste a mistake in the comment it says: `//In inspector, drag in the GameObject that has this script attached to it` So the reference is not the object initialized by the constructor

Answer (score 0):

The "constructor"method of a monobehaviour is either `Start or Awake` [see here for their order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html). So you cannot do anything in their constructor.

Second you cannot create new MB by `new MyMB()` you need to use `gameObject.AddComponent<MyMB>()`, and use the result of that to assign reference to anything else. There is the same for getting `gameObject.GetComponent<MyMB>()`.

I highly you look up some tutorials for Unity as you cannot just use what is used in C# in Unity. [Here's a comprehensive overview](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingConcepts.html).